# How to disable mouse acceleration on Debian?

Tags: debian, x11, mouse

I tried to navigate here: **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mouse.conf/**

But in this directory is no **90-mouse.conf**

How do I disable mouse acceleration?

Answer (score 3):

- create a new empty file

  sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf
- paste the following lines into the file

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "my_mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
    Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

- logout and login (to restart the session)

more examples can be found here: [Setting mouse acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Setting_mouse_acceleration) (but note that the path to .conf file in your Linux distribution is different)