# How to disable mouse acceleration on Raspberry OS / Debian 11?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mouse

I want to disable mouse acceleration completely in my RasPi 4. Never neither used nor needed such a function.

```
pg@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

pg@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.84-v8+ #1613 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 5 12:03:08 GMT 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux


pg@raspberrypi:~ $ xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse Consumer Control id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]

pg@raspberrypi:~ $ xinput --list-props 6
Device 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (153): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (282):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (283):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (284):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (285):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (286):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (287): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (288): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (289):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (290):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (291):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (292):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (293): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (294): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (295):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (296):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (297):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (298): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (299): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (300): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (301):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (302):    0, 0
    Device Node (303):  "/dev/input/event0"
    Device Product ID (304):    1578, 16642
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):   1
```

Tried unsuccesfully:

- creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf` as per [How to disable mouse acceleration on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518019/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-on-debian)
- creating `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/95-mouse-accel.conf` as per https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/535ng5/how_to_disable_mouse_acceleration_with_libinput/
- using `"Device Accel Constant Deceleration"` as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity
- playing around with values of `libinput Accel Speed` and `Coordinate Transformation Matrix`as per https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/
- creating different `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-acceleration.conf` as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mouse_acceleration#Setting_mouse_acceleration
- `xset 5 1` as per https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=748412#4
- setting `Access Profile Enabled -1` as I *thought* https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/ indicates - clearly I thunk wrong

Each option tested one by one, first reloading lightdm, then as there's no change rebooting system.

The same mouse works perfectly fine on my daily driver, also Debian 11 (lower kernel).

---

Tested with Gentoo, no mouse lag whatsoever. Some issue with Debian ARM version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to disable mouse acceleration completely:

1. Open `/boot/cmdline.txt` in a text editor
2. Add to the command line `usbhid.mousepoll=0`
3. Reboot